# Mouse click doesn't work, mousemove does

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, mouseevent

I try to trigger an event on mouse click but my event never start. First I  I didn't select the good area but the mouse event "mousemove" trigger my event. I don't understand how it is possible...
Does someone has an explaination or a solution to this problem?

```
d3.select("#chart").on("mousemove", function(){console.log("this");});
d3.select("#chart").on("click", function(){console.log("that");});
```

I can see "this" but not "that".

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806736/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work) but that doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: there is a spell mistake `on("clic"`, it should be `on("click"`

Comment: I badly copy my code but click doesn't work too.

Comment: Getting help with this is very unlikely, unless you share your code or provide a [mcve] at least.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken the spelling of `click`, change

```
d3.select("#chart").on("clic", function(){console.log("that");});
```

to

```
d3.select("#chart").on("click", function(){console.log("that");});
```

Comment: can you please reproduce it on jsfiddle and pass the link

Comment: My code is actually more than 1000 lines long and everything is binded then I don't know what I should pass...

Answer (score 0):

You must use event 'click' ... not 'clic'

Answer (score 0):

Show bigger part of your code. I`ve tried here to bind click event and everything works fine: [D3.js test click](http://jsfiddle.net/fv3vj60j/)

```
d3.select('#one').on('click', function(){console.log('Clicked!')})
```